# Hide directories from listing, but don't disable directory listings

Tags: apache, directory, hide

For example I want to hide the directory `foo` in the root of the public directory. I want to show the contents of the directory, but I don't want `foo` to be in there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i asked the question, then logged into my account after I realized my error.

well i guess my only question left then is this one: [Apache: Block all directories except for listed ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076915/apache-block-all-directories-except-for-listed-ones)