# Apache: Block all directories except for listed ones

Tags: regex, directory, apache2, access-control

I want to block people from accessing every directory except for `/sandbox`, `/WebDev` and `/Projects`

I tried this:

```
<Directory ^/(?<!sandbox|Projects|WebDev)+(/.*)>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

but it gave a 500 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way is something like:

```
<Directory />
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /sandbox>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /WebDev>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /Projects>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: yeah, that makes sense but I was hoping that there would be a quicker regex way to add it faster. If there aren't any other answers this would work for sure.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the right `tested` way you want with a `RegEx`.

I suggest you use this in the Apache configuration file itself, not within `.htaccess` as it may not work correctly on some default OS's Apache configs (such as Ubuntu's) unless if you corrected the other related configurations to make it work within `.htaccess` (i.e.`AllowOverride`.. etc)

```
    <Directory />
            Order allow,deny
            deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory ~ "/(sandbox|Projects|WebDev)">
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Yes, it is an `OLD` questions, but this answer might help someone.. :-)